How can I make this fail to compile if the wrong argument is passed?
The static assert is always firing, what's a good way to fail compilation if these conditions aren't met?
template <typename T>
static int type_to_ascii(T type)
{
    if (std::is_same_v<T, double>)
        return 0;
    else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, float>)
        return 1;
    else if constexpr (std::is_integral_v<type>)
        return 2;
    else
        static_assert(false, "Error");


}

int main()
{
    type_to_ascii(4);
}

